# Find the solution to the following differential equation: $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x - y}{xy} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The instructor in our Differential Equations class gave us the following to solve:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x - y}{xy} $$

It was an item under separable differential equations. I have gotten as far as $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{x} $ which to me doesn't really seem much. I don't even know if it really is a separable equation.

I tried treating it as a *homogeneous equation*, multiplying both sides with $y$ to get (Do note that I just did the following for what it's worth)...
$$ y\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - \frac{y}{x} $$
$$ vx (v + x \frac{dv}{dx}) = 1 - v $$
$$ v^2x + vx^2 \frac{dv}{dx} = 1 - v $$
$$ vx^2 \frac{dv}{dx} = 1 - v - v^2x$$

I am unsure how to proceed at this point.

What should I first do to solve the given differential equation?

Comment: Try the Ansatz $z=x^ay^b$.

Comment: @J.G. I tried 4 such type of substitutions.No result.

Comment: @Unique I didn't get anywhere with it either.

Comment: @Mark Johnson I don't think, method of separation of variables will work here, I tried many different ways but not getting any result.

Answer (score 3):

> We write the differential equation as
>
> \begin{align*}
> xyy^\prime=x-y\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> and follow the receipt I.237 in the german book *[Differentialgleichungen, Lösungsmethoden und Lösungen I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3519020173)* by E. Kamke.

We consider $y=y(x)$ as the independent variable and use the substitution
\begin{align*}
v=v(y)=\frac{1}{y-x(y)}=\left(y-x(y)\right)^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

We obtain from (2)
\begin{align*}
v&=\frac{1}{y-x}\qquad\to\qquad  x=y-\frac{1}{v}\\
v^{\prime}&=(-1)(y-x)^{-2}\left(1-x^{\prime}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{y^{\prime}}-1\right)v^2
\end{align*}
From (1) we  get by taking $v$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y^{\prime}}=\frac{xy}{x-y}=\left(y-\frac{1}{v}\right)y(-v)=y-y^2v\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Putting (2) and (3) together we get
>   \begin{align*}
> v^{\prime}=\left(y-y^2v-1\right)v^2
> \end{align*}
>   respectively
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{v^{\prime}+y^2v^3-(y-1)v^2=0}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> and observe (4) is an instance of an *[Abel equation of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind)*.

Comment: What is the final result?

Comment: @Unique: OP was asking for a first step. Here we give a transformation to a differential equation which has a simpler form. To get the final result follow the link given in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a homogeneous ordinary differential equation.

In order to be homogeneous, one should get the ODE in the form
$\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$,

i.e the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is some function of $\frac{y}{x}$.

If yo try that for your equation, you get the form
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-y/x}{y}$ 
which is clearly not a function of $y/x$ due to the presence of $y$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

This equation is not homogeneous for $(x,y)$.

One simple test for homogeneity $\bigl(y' = F(\frac xy)\bigr)$ is if $y' = f(x,y) = f(tx,ty)$ for any real $t$. Here, this is not at all the case.

As a matter of fact, I don't think this is an ordinary differential equation whose family of solutions is in the form of common functions.  If $y'$ were $1-y\over xy$ we could substitute $xy = r$ to get $$r' = \frac rx +\frac 1{\frac rx} - 1$$ which is homogeneous for $(x, r)$ but as posed I have a feeling that this DE does not have a "nice" solution.